# Close a file when creating a list from open()

Tags: python, file, list

I've seen this idiom in [Dive Into Python 3](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/):

```
l = list(open('strcpy.c'))
```

The question is, how can I `close` the file?

Is something happening behind the scenes?

I couldn't find this information in the book.

Comment: since there are no pointers to the open filehandle, i think it just garbage collects on the next pass ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file will be closed when its object is garbage-collected. In CPython, this happens pretty much immediately after that line is executed, because the file is never assigned to a variable. In other Pythons, such as Jython or IronPython, this may not happen right away (or at all), though all open files are always closed when the process exits.

For this reason, a better approach is to close the file explicitly using 'with':

```
with open("strcpy.c") as infile:
    l = list(infile)
```

An advantage of this is that the file will be properly closed even if an exception occurs in reading it; you don't have to manually write code for this case using a `try/except` block.

A `with` statement can be written on one line if you want to stick with the concise one-liner.  :-)

That said, I do sometimes use this idiom myself in short-running scripts where having the file open a wee bit longer than it strictly needs to be isn't a big deal. An advantage is that you don't clutter things up with a variable (`infile` in this case) pointing to a closed file.

Comment: Heh, 3 identical answers at the same time. This one's the best of those, though.

Comment: this is the best :) it actually explains that it is gc'd ... and in cython thats pretty much immediat

Comment: Thanks for the insight on `CPython`. Too bad the `find a duplicate` sport is so fast nowadays! I wonder what interesting information I could have lost if that was even a bit faster :D.

Answer (score 2):

From [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

You can use it like this:

```
with open('strcpy.c') as f:
    l = list(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would *never* open a file without a context manager:

```
with open('strcpy.c') as myfile:
    l = list(myfile)
# do stuff with l here
```

When using the context manager, the file is automagically closed at the end of the indentation block.

Comment: opening for reading does not lock files.  also with cython `list(open(...))` will garbage collect the FH almost immediatly. its not such a cardinal sin to do something like `list(open(...))` as you make it out to be... (+1 all the same since contextmanager is better form)